# Date difference changing based on timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a server date time which is also CST and a date based of chicago timezone, when i find the difference between two dates the value is different for different timezones.

I am not able to get to the problem.

1. Date A is my Chicago time `2019-05-22T04:02:14-05:00`
2. Date B is my server time `2019-05-20T01:39:34-04:00`
3. Hours difference between them 51 when my timezone is set to EST

When i change my timezone to **IST**

1. Date A is my Chicago time `2019-05-22T04:03:34-05:00`
2. Date B is my server time `2019-05-20T01:39:34+05:30`
3. Hours difference between them 60 when my timezone is set to IST

**Why is there a difference in hours when the dates are same in both the cases?**

```
  getIntervalTime(dateA, dateB): ITimer {
    console.log("Date A is my Chicago time", dateA)
    console.log("Date B is my server time", dateB)
    console.log(moment.utc(dateA).diff(moment.utc(dateB), "hours"));

    intervalHours = moment.utc(dateA).diff(moment.utc(dateB), "hours")    
  }
```

Comment: why are you considering server time? The time difference will be taken from the client side browsers, right

Comment: I want to hours difference to be server time and time in chicago right now, irrespective of browser timezone or time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you gave two very different server times. They are not referencing the same actual point in time.  In each case, `01:39:34` is the *local* time in the time zone offset provided.

```
2019-05-20T01:39:34-04:00 (EDT) = 2019-05-20T05:39:34Z (UTC) = 2019-05-20T11:09:34+05:30 (IST)
2019-05-20T01:39:34+05:30 (IST) = 2019-04-19T20:09:34Z (UTC) = 2019-04-19T16:09:34-04:00 (EDT)
```

As you can see just by comparing the UTC times, there is a 9.5 hour difference between these two timestamps.  This is also reflected in the difference between the two offsets (`5.5` - `-4` = `9.5`).

This is a common source of confusion, as often people view the `+` or `-` sign as an *operator*, and thus think of it as an instruction ("Oh, I see a plus or minus so I must need to add or subtract this value to get to the local time").   But in reality it is not an operator, but the [*sign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)) of the offset.  Positive offset values are ahead of UTC, while negative offset values are behind UTC.  (Alternatively one can think of positive offsets as being east of GMT, while negative offsets are west of GMT.)

**In other words, the date and time portion of an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted timestamp are *already* converted to the context provided.**

Also note that the time zone of your server won't really matter, nor should it.  Now is now - [time zones don't change that](https://dilbert.com/strip/1998-03-14).  Thus, in most cases you should simply use the UTC time.